# Transferring value of variable from one unrelated class to another

Tags: oop, inheritance, python-2.7

If I want to create a program using `Python2.7` where:

1) There are three classes, namely Tagging, Commenting, and Posting

2) The `self.content` for both `Tagging` and `Commenting` classes will be sent to the `self.compact` of class `Posting`

```
class Tagging: # Handles Tagging - Create new Tags
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
        self.initialTag = ""
    def doTag(self): #Tag people
         self.initialTag = raw_input("Name to Tag: ")
         self.content.append(self.initialTag)
    #Tagging can only be done if the user created new post.

class Commenting: #Handles Commenting - Create new Comments
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
        self.initialComment = ""
    def doComment(self): #Commenting on Posts
        self.initialComment = raw_input("Comment: ")
        self.content.append(self.initialComment)
    #Commenting can only be done on Posts. No Post means no Comment. (Same goes to Tags)

class Posting: #Handles Posting - Create new Posts
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = [] #Content of the post
        self.initialPost = ""
        self.compact = [] #Post that contains the Post, Comments, and Tags
        #How do I do this?

    def doPost(self):
        self.initialPost = raw_input("Post: ")
        self.content.append(self.initialPost)
```

I tried inheriting `class Posting` to both `class Tagging` and `class Commenting` but I think using Inheritance just for one single `variable` of `class Posting` is illogical.

Can anyone suggest me a better way?

And additional question: Are the class `Tagging` and class `Commenting` having `Aggregation` relationship to class `Posting`? Or is it an `Association` relationship? (word definition by UML)

Comment: Why is in your opinion a base-class to capture the shared concepts between classes a bad concept?

Comment: @JoachimRosskopf Actually, I was thinking if Python has any built-in function for transferring value of variable. So, you are saying Inheritance is the best way to approach such problem?

Comment: Why dont you simply pass the values through the __init__ function?

Comment: What do instances of these classes represent? I'm not sure they should be classes at all. Is "Posting" supposed to be a verb, representing the act of posting, or is it supposed to be a noun, representing... something?

Comment: @DanielSanchez Could you post sample code on how to do it? I apologize for being a beginner :((

Comment: As far as I have understood, yo want the Tagging.content and Commenting.content into Posting.compact, so, how about get that values in the inicializer of Posting? (__ init __(self, TaggingContent, CommentingContent) ): self.compact = TaggingContent + CommentingContent

Comment: @DanielSanchez Could you be kind to post a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, just example code in "__ main __" part:

```
class Tagging: # Handles Tagging - Create new Tags
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
        self.initialTag = ""
    def doTag(self): #Tag people
         self.initialTag = raw_input("Name to Tag: ")
         self.content.append(self.initialTag)
    #Tagging can only be done if the user created new post.

class Commenting: #Handles Commenting - Create new Comments
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
        self.initialComment = ""
    def doComment(self): #Commenting on Posts
        self.initialComment = raw_input("Comment: ")
        self.content.append(self.initialComment)
    #Commenting can only be done on Posts. No Post means no Comment. (Same goes to Tags)

class Posting: #Handles Posting - Create new Posts
    def __init__(self, TaggingContent, CommentingContent):
        self.content = [] #Content of the post
        self.initialPost = ""
        self.compact = TaggingContent + CommentingContent #Post that contains the Post, Comments, and Tags
        #How do I do this?

    def doPost(self):
        self.initialPost = raw_input("Post: ")
        self.content.append(self.initialPost)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    T = Tagging()
    C = Commenting()
    ##Do stuff here with tagging and commenting....
    P = Posting(T.content, C.content)
    #Do stuff with posting
```

That way you have the content from Tagging and Commenting into compact from Posting, or am I wrong about what you need?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. By the way, what does `__name__ == "__main__":` do? Does it always return True? and just another question, are those three classes an Aggregation Relationship?

Comment: And what if I have all three classes in different Python files? Then I have no choice but to use Inheritance, right?

Comment: 1.- (__ name __ == "__main__") just tests if the name of the current module you are working in is the "main" module, so in case you import that module the code in the scope will not be executed. It just return true in case you not have not imported the module.                     2.-They are not an agregation relationship, you are just using the data from one class to another, you not have an instance of that class inside the other class.                                          3.- Yo can have the classes in diferent python modules or files and still use this method without trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much! Then what should I do if I want to reverse the execution order to 1.Post -> 2.Comment -> Tag? Won't Posting raise error since there are no comments and tags yet?

Comment: Changing the order just means that you should pick the data in posting, and then pass the values to commenting and tagging the same way we did before to pass it to posting through the init function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure in OOP that a set of classes provides obeys a certain contract you normally define an interface.

Python does not provide interfaces directly, but instead it's common to use duck-typeing by the use of something like [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) or [hasattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr), which means, that if your object has a content-property use it, if not, raise an error.

Another possiblity to emulate interfaces is available since Python 2.6 by means of [Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'isinstance' returns TRUE and not the value of the variable. Is there any other way? All I can think of is Inheritance.

Comment: No, what I meant is, that you can check, eg. check with isinstance, if an argument is "Tagging", or "Commenting". The other possiblity is, if an argument hasattr "content".